# Expected Declaration UIAlert View

Tags: swift

```
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: default, handler: nil)
```

I get Expected Declaration Error.

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: What exactly is the error? The code you posted has a few errors.Is this really the code you have?

Comment: @Hello, Please first check your code and then upload it to the stack overflow. You will understand what is the error. Just don't upload the small issues.

Comment: voting to close it as a typo

Comment: Sorry I realized it later and I don't know how to edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil))
```

Comment: Thank you : ) Sorry I realized it later and I don't know how to edit the question.